# android cyclic inheritance involving between Fragment Activity and Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Simply Saying I have 2 fragment A & B and 1 MainActivity. 
MainActivity Implements both A&B Interface
But when I tried to Implement Interface to fragment A from MainActivity Interface, it says:

> cyclic inheritance involving 'fragment A activity'

I already search for another similar question, but it seems still doesn't worked for me. By the way, I want to do this is because I want to pass an Custom ArrayList to Fragment A Activity.

Here is my code

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements MostPopularArticle.OnFragmentInteractionListenerMP,
    LatestArticle.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public interface MainActivityFliterMethod {
        void FilterList(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> getSetListValueData);
    }
 }
```

Fragment A Code

```
public class MostPopularArticle extends Fragment implements 
MainActivity.MainActivityFliterMethod {
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListenerMP {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteractionMostPopular(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> arrayList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ordinary the IDE should indicate circular references ... it might be similar to this default [example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating#DefineInterface), while putting interfaces into their own files is often more easy. and you'd have to pass the `Activity`'s listener somehow into the `Fragment`, so that it can be triggered from within there.

```
public interface FragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteractionMostPopular(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> arrayList);
}

public interface FilterMethod {
    void FilterList(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> getSetListValueData);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentInteractionListener {

    /** Constructor */
    public MainActivity() {}

    @Override
    void onFragmentInteractionMostPopular(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> arrayList) {

    }
}

public class MostPopularArticle extends Fragment implements FilterMethod {

    private FragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /** Constructor */
    public MostPopularArticle(Context context, FragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        this.setContext(context);
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    void FilterList(ArrayList<getSetListValueData> getSetListValueData) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example link, It help me solved out my problem, turn out that I don't  even need to implement another interface to my fragment

Comment: @GAMETTXD a single interface method is usually enough, eg. to notice of an event. and when extending the interface with further methods, one cannot miss adding the methods elsewhere; it's enforced, for every single implementation of it.